# Why is the compiler unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI when I try to Verify & Publish my contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, etherscan, truffle-contract

Another dev no longer connected to our project deployed this contract, and I'm trying to Verify & Publish it on Etherscan now.

What am I doing wrong?

I do know that the dev who built this used Truffle, if that's helpful.

Here's the error I'm getting:

Compiler debug log: Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : BasicToken, ERC20, ERC20Basic, SafeMath, SeedsToken, StandardToken But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)

**Here's the code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances.
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    uint256 _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // require (_value <= _allowance);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   */
  function increaseApproval (address _spender, uint _addedValue)
    returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval (address _spender, uint _subtractedValue)
    returns (bool success) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

/**
* @title Seeds token. Implements Standard ERC20 token
*/
contract SeedsToken is StandardToken {

  string public name = 'SeedsToken';
  string public symbol = 'SEEDS';
  uint public decimals = 10;
  uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000000000000000000;

  function SeedsToken() {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }

}
```

Comment: To begin with, you should use the exact compiler version (not `pragma solidity ^0.4.11;`). Do you know what it is? If not, do you know what Truffle version was used (compiler version might be inferable from it)? Also, what is the contract address?

Comment: Hey @goodvibration - I suspected this was the issue, thanks!  I don't know the exact compiler version (I only have the information shared in the code here).  I don't know what Truffle version was used either, but the tokens were minted in October of 2017, which I imagine may help us figure this out.  Any ideas from there?  The contract address is 0x61404d2d3f2100b124d6827d3f2ddf6233cd71c0.

Comment: I tried to verify your contract with every compiler version between 0.4.11 and 0.4.18 (which was released on Oct 18, 2017). Verification failed in each one of them. Perhaps because of optimization level (I used `runs=200`, which is the default in all compiler versions AFAIK). Perhaps because of some other reason.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Any suggestions re: what to do now?

Comment: If you check the JSON artifacts in your build/contracts/, you should see a a `compiler` field to get the exact version. Truffle disables the optimizer by default.

Comment: This is super helpful to know re: Truffle disabling the Optimizer - thanks!  Half of the problem is solved.  However, the code I shared above is all I have access to, so given that, how can I check the JSON artifacts in my build/contracts?

Comment: Will someone please answer me?